# How is inheritance in Java different from real world inheritance?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I got this question in an interview. By real world inheritance the interviewer meant things like the off springs inherit some wealth , some characteristics of parents etc.,

I have a feeling that this question is something that can be debated and does not make a good interview question.

Can this question be answered well ?

Comment: "something that can be debated" makes a great interview question

Comment: I'm not sure this really fits well on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), but it's at least a lot closer fit than here (at least in my opinion). The answer s/he was probably hoping for was that "real-world" inheritance doesn't even come close to respecting the LSP though.

Comment: There has never been - to the best of my knowledge - any controversy over the true paternity of a java class.  Maybe things would be more interesting if there were.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this question can be answered very well and I think it's a good interview question; if you can answer this, it shows that you understand one of the fundamental concepts of object oriented programming.

Inheritance in object oriented programming means something completely different than biological inheritance. Inheritance in OO means **specialization** and implies an **is a** relationship: an instance of a subclass *is a* specialized kind of instance of its superclass.

For example, suppose you have `class Cat extends Animal`. A Cat *is an* Animal.

Sometimes people use the words "Parent" and "Child" in examples of class inheritance, where they would have a `class Parent` and a `class Child extends Parent`. That's wrong: A Child *is not a* (specialized kind of) Parent.

Comment: Hehe... `class Child extends Parent`... I've never heard that example to explain inheritance.

But it's kind of funny. Imagine the population growth if all children became parents the moment they came into existence...

Btw, I definitely think this was the answer that the interviewer was looking for. I do not think he was looking for an answer about multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Alderath I'm a moderator in a Java programming forum, it happens regularly that people ask a question with an example with `class Child extends Parent`...

Answer (score 1):

This is a very vague question. Only thing I can think of off the top of my head is that Java only inherits from one parent while Real Life inheritance can have more than one.It is arguable though as people use interfaces as a work-around.

Comment: Interface only allow an object to behave polymorphically. That's not multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

In the real world multiple inheritance is allowed. For example among animals children extend the genes of both parents. In Java however, a child may only have one parent.

Answer (score 0):

In my culture, children inherit their family name (to you java geeks, a family name is kind of like a package name) from their father (To the java geeks, a father is like a special kind of superclass and a mother is another special kind of superclass.  Each child has exactly one father and one mother.)

In java, a class can have any package name (within the standard limits) and there is one superclass and multiple (0, 1, or more superinterfaces).

Answer (score 0):

In Java, Inheritance is the property by which one class extends or inherits the properties of other class. So if you take the real life inheritance example, a son inherits the mix of DNA qualities from his father and mother. 
So if you are asking for a difference between real life inheritance and Java Inheritance, the major difference i find is, you cannot inherit multiple inheritance class in Java whereas a multiple inheritance is possible in real life.

Else, you can also think Inheriting the wealth and property of Real Life as the Multiple Level Inheritance in Java, where you inherit the property of the super class from the subclass and later passing it on at different level.